# Variance of product of a matrix and vector using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the variance of the product of matrix A and vector b. As it was mathematically discussed on another post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365166/what-is-the-variance-of-a-constant-matrix-times-a-random-vector, I have tried to do the calculation in python.

To recap, we have
\begin{equation}
Y = \bf{Ab} 
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation}
\bf{b} \sim N(\mu_b, \bf{I}\sigma_b^2)
\end{equation}

Therefore
\begin{equation}
Var(Y) = \bf{A}\sigma_b^2\bf{A}^T
\end{equation}
I have tried this code with

```
import numpy as np
import statistics

A = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)   # some 4 by 3 array
b = np.array([2,4,5])              # some 3 by 1 vector

Y = np.dot(A,b)
statistics.variance(Y)
>> 1815

Vb = np.dot(np.identity(b.shape[0]), statistics.variance(b))
np.dot(A.dot(Vb), np.transpose(A))
>> array([[ 10.,  28.,  46.,  64.],
       [ 28., 100., 172., 244.],
       [ 46., 172., 298., 424.],
       [ 64., 244., 424., 604.]])
```

However, the `statistic.variance(Y)` outputs a different result compared to `np.dot(A.dot(Vb), np.transpose(A))`.

I wonder how should I do it properly in python?

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test formulas like these *numerically*, you need to compute *sample* statistics, like this:

```python
    import numpy as np
    A = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)  # Note: A is a fixed matrix
    b_avg = np.array([2, 4, 5])  # b is random, with a mean vector
    b_var = 1e0 * np.eye(b_avg.size)  # and a (co)variance matrix

    # generate a random sample of b vectors    
    n_sample = 10**4
    b_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(
        mean=b_avg, cov=b_var, size=n_sample).T

    # compute sample moments (each column is a sample)
    b_avg_smp = b_sample.mean(axis=1)
    b_var_smp = np.cov(b_sample)

    # compare sample moments to population moments
    print('b vector: statistics')
    print('Averages (population vs. sample):',
          b_avg.tolist(), b_avg_smp.round(1).tolist(), sep='\n')
    print('Variances (population vs. sample):',
          b_var.tolist(), b_var_smp.round(1).tolist(), sep='\n')
```

This will give something like this:

```
b vector: statistics
Averages (population vs. sample):
[2, 4, 5]
[2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
Variances (population vs. sample):
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
[[1.0, -0.0, 0.0], [-0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

i.e. the sample statistics are consistent with the specified $b$ distribution.

Then we can transform the $b$ sample into a $y$ sample, and do the analogous comparison, using your analytically computed $y$ moments, i.e.

```python
    # transform b moments into y moments (@ is matrix multiply)
    y_avg = A @ b_avg
    y_var = A @ b_var @ A.T

    # transform b sample into y sample, and compute sample moments
    y_sample = A @ b_sample
    y_avg_smp = y_sample.mean(axis=1)
    y_var_smp = np.cov(y_sample)
    
    # compare population vs. sample moments
    print('y vector: statistics')
    print('Averages (population vs. sample):',
          y_avg.tolist(), y_avg_smp.round(1).tolist(), sep='\n')
    print('Variances (population vs. sample):',
          y_var.tolist(), y_var_smp.round(1).tolist(), sep='\n')
```

This will give something like this:

```
y vector: statistics
Averages (population vs. sample):
[14, 47, 80, 113]
[13.9, 46.8, 79.7, 112.7]
Variances (population vs. sample):
[[5.0, 14.0, 23.0, 32.0], [14.0, 50.0, 86.0, 122.0], [23.0, 86.0, 149.0, 212.0], [32.0, 122.0, 212.0, 302.0]]
[[5.0, 14.0, 23.1, 32.1], [14.0, 50.1, 86.1, 122.1], [23.1, 86.1, 149.0, 212.0], [32.1, 122.1, 212.0, 302.0]]
```

i.e. the sample $y$ statistics are consistent with the analytically computed $y$ distribution.

(Alternatively, the [uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) package will automatically do linearized error propagation for Gaussian random variables.)

Comment: Thank you very much, @GeoMatt22, I got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing some concepts. It's hard to explain but i will try.

statistics.variance(b) gives you the variance of n samples in variable b in 1 dimension. The variance matrix for b is a 1x1 matrix.

Vb is the variance matrix for 3 dimensional sample with several samples and zero covarinace between the dimensions. But it is not the variance matrix for b.

The definition of A for b is wrong. It works because np.dot uses automatically b.T, but conceptually is wrong.

I hope this help to understand it.

Comment: Thanks. Would you suggest any simulations as I showed in the code above to demonstrate how to calculate the variance of Y as in the scenario with Y=Ab where b ~ $N(\mu,\bf{I\sigma_b^2})$ ? Thank you!